# laravel command not found on ubuntu termnal after inalling laravel and giving it a path to composer

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, terminal

I already tried to fix this myself multiple times but with no luck so far.

So i just installed laravel i added path

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

to the (.bashrc) file then i saved everything and run

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

to update everything after that i run

```
laravel -v
```

and it shows that everything is installed  however after i close the terminal and open the new one and run

```
laravel -v
```

it shows laravel: command not found.

Already tried this [I get "laravel: command not found" on Ubuntu 20.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61395786/i-get-laravel-command-not-found-on-ubuntu-20-04)

I am running on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Here are screenshots from my terminal:

https://postimg.cc/4mH4Dznf

https://postimg.cc/TLQqvz7D

https://postimg.cc/qgxM4kxY

Thank you for your help in advance ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to run the command "source ~/.bashrc" each time you open a new terminal session in order for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Yep i worked :) Thank you very much!!!  However any ideas how i can use laravel without running "source ~/.bashrc" every time i open a new terminal window ?